# Is there spy hardware that can be attached to laptops and if so how to detect them?

Tags: windows, hardware, spyware

A while back I lived in shared apartments. One day I returned to my room and found my laptop screen frame open. Since then I keep get log in attempts to my accounts.

I scanned my laptop with multiple anti-virus software but nothing is detected.

Is there spy hardware that can be attached to laptops and if so how to detect them?

Comment: Yes, there are "spy" hardware. If hardware is attached, then you take the laptop to a technician to look for strange "additions".

Comment: is there any software way to detect such addition?

Comment: No, software depends on hardware.

Comment: okay, is there a name for such devices or additions?

Comment: It depends on what the device is actually doing. Keyloggers are popular and simple.

Comment: Laptops are tightly packed. It's hard to add something inside and hide it well. If a spying device was not installed by a professional, chances are you can find it just by looking. You can open your laptop (this will void your warranty) and look for stuff fixed in place with tape or dangling around. Before that, look at the screws: do they look like they were never used before? Usually screwdrivers will leave tiny dents on them.

Comment: If your device has been compromised physically, the only surefire of getting rid of any HW additions is to get rid of it. This is what I'd do. And of course, change all your passwords on a different "clean" device.

Comment: @A.Hersean the laptop was found already open.

Comment: @schroeder It's unclear if the lid was open or the frame. The screen frame is not meant to be opened, and there's no room here to hide anything.

Comment: @A.Hersean to say that the "frame" was open when you meant that the "lid was open" is very strange, and given that the concern is hardware-based, it's a safe assumption that the innards were exposed.

Comment: @schroeder On this website, I always assume English is not the main language of the writers. But you might be right, of course.

Comment: @A.Hersean agreed, but it's the combo that is supporting my assumption